# how to sum the columns in a dataframe if one column is passed as none in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Summation of 2 columns (brand and country) to get the KPi values
`data['kpi'][(data.brand=='ABC') & (data.country is None)].sum()`  This gives me 0

I was expecting the above line will be equal to the below and which in turn gives the answer

```
data['kpi'][(data.brand=='ABC')].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `data.country is None` yields only a single `bool` `False` value, not the needed *logical vector*. One could expect that the expression `data.country == None` works, but for some (unknown to me) reason, it doesn't with `pandas.DataFrame` columns (it yields a vector of all `False` values, regardless of `None` items).
What I found to work is the expression `data.country.isnull()`, i. e.:

```
data['kpi'][(data.brand=='ABC') & data.country.isnull()].sum()
```

Comment: The proposed solution does not equal to data['kpi'][(data.brand=='ABC')].sum(). Since the objective is sum the kpi values based on the brand 'ABC' excluding country values

Comment: @athiq - Sorry, I don't gather what you mean. You should specify some sample data.